# Кнопки внизу экрана - Android

Tags: android, button

Добрый день. Как в Android сделать кнопки, прижатыми к низу экрана так, как это сделано на картинке?

[image: example]

Comment: поставить им `gravity="bottom"`

Comment: Android Studio всего лишь одна из сред разработки. Ваш вопрос не относится к самой Android Studio, для получения одинакового результата можно использовать любую среду разработки под Android. Приложите разметку для вашей активити.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К примеру, таким образом:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`LinearLayout` размещаете внизу, в них 2 кнопки, раздаете им одинаковый `layout_weight` и стилизируете их как Вам необходимо.